# How to get the data from an adjacent column when clicking on a button/icon in the same row using JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I was able to get the data from the first and second columns, but after I added an icon, it's not working anymore. I'd assume it needs to get to another level so that it can then go in and reach that wanted cell data, but I don't know how to go about that and He knows I've tried.

This is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/santosonit/g4mv1jzb/8/#&togetherjs=5zJ4GjgMlH)

and here's the code snippet:

```
function deleteTask() {
  const dataTr = event.target.parentNode;
  const cancelTaskId = dataTr.parentNode.querySelectorAll("td")[1].innerText;
  const clientId = dataTr.parentNode.querySelectorAll("td")[0].innerText;
  let data = [];
  data.push([clientId, cancelTaskId]);

  const td = event.target.parentNode;
  const tr = td.parentNode;
  tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
}
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ## [Element.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)
>
> The `closest()` method of the Element interface traverses the element and its parents (heading toward the document root) until it finds a node that matches the specified CSS selector.

```js
const dataTr = event.target.closest('tr');
const dataTd = dataTr.querySelectorAll('td');
const cancelTaskId = dataTd[1].innerText;
const clientId = dataTd[0].innerText;
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry, but I've replaced the piece as suggested and it erased all rows. I still have such a limited knowledge, so I'm not sure I've applied it correctly.

Comment: That's probably ```const dataTr = event.target.closest('td');```, instead.